# Anyone experience PCI Compliance scan create errors in application server?

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, webserver, pci-compliance

I'm running GlassFish 3.1.2 behind Apache 2.4.10 web server and mod_jk on CentOS 6 Linux server. I've observed PCI Compliance scans consistently create errors in the GlassFish server.log file, which cause my web app running in GlassFish to become unavailable (file not found). Basically, the web app dies, but the domain continues to run, although it continuously generates errors from that point forward.

Could anyone confirm this is known behavior? If so, are there any known workarounds?

Or, is the only solution to bring my application down for the 1-2 days it takes to run the PCI Compliance scan?

Here are typical errors/warning I see when running such scans (these from GlassFish's server.log file):

> [#|2014-11-13T16:09:46.849-0800|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011:
>   Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context ,
>   because request parameters  have already been read, or
>   ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

---

> [#|2014-11-14T11:56:40.218-0800|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ORBUtil|_ThreadID=515;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|IOP00710020:
>   Error in GIOP magic org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: WARNING: IOP00710020:
>   Error in GIOP magic  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 20 completed: Maybe  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy196.giopMagicError(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.parseGiopHeader(MessageBase.java:201)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageParserImpl.parseBytes(MessageParserImpl.java:216)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.parseBytesAndDispatchMessages(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1619)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrategy(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1486)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1084)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
>   |#]

---

> [#|2014-11-14T11:58:57.231-0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=53;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0051:
>   ProcessorTask exception. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid
>   packet magic number: 1603 pos=0 lastValid=166 end=0   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ajp.AjpInputBuffer.readAjpMessageHeader(AjpInputBuffer.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ajp.AjpProcessorTask.parseRequest(AjpProcessorTask.java:107)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:706)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) |#]

---

> [#|2014-11-14T12:03:28.651-0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet|_ThreadID=532;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC6117:
>   File
>   "/home/glassfish/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/docroot/login.jsp"
>   not found|#]

---

> [#|2014-11-14T12:03:29.062-0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet|_ThreadID=533;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC6117:
>   File
>   "/home/glassfish/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/docroot/spiffymcgee.jsp"
>   not foun d|#]

---

> [#|2014-11-14T12:03:29.634-0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=531;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0042:
>   Error creating internal request. java.lang.NumberFormatException  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.Ascii.parseLong(Ascii.java:236)  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.ByteChunk.getLong(ByteChunk.java:554)    at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.MessageBytes.getLong(MessageBytes.java:715)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Request.getContentLengthLong(Request.java:378)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.prepareRequest(ProcessorTask.java:1457)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.parseRequest(ProcessorTask.java:947)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:706)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) |#]

---

> [#|2014-11-14T12:03:34.250-0800|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=62;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Internal
>   Server error: %. java.io.CharConversionException: EOF     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:140)  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:257)  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:235)  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.http.HttpRequestURIDecoder.decode(HttpRequestURIDecoder.java:98)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.lookupHandler(ContainerMapper.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:194)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) |#]

---

> [#|2014-11-14T12:03:34.427-0800|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Internal
>   Server error: %server.policy java.io.CharConversionException:
>   isHexDigit    at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:145)  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:257)  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:235)  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.http.HttpRequestURIDecoder.decode(HttpRequestURIDecoder.java:98)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.lookupHandler(ContainerMapper.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:194)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) |#]

---